# Can a finite sum of square roots be an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, radicals, faq

Can a sum of a finite number of square roots of integers be an integer? If yes can a sum of two square roots of integers be an integer?

The square roots need to be irrational.

Comment: like $\sqrt{9} + \sqrt{16} = 7$?

Comment: If you choose only integers that are squares of other integers this will always work, since their square roots are integers and the sum of a finite number of integers is an integer.

Comment: I think [this link](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/square-roots-have-no-unexpected-linear-relationships/) is a pretty good answer to your question. However, it might be at a level which is too advanced for you, since this is a pretty natural question to ask relatively early on in life, but it takes some significantly more difficult mathematics to prove. The direct, yes/no answer to the question is "Yes, but only if the numbers inside the square roots were already perfect squares," or equivalently "If you've already done all the simplifying that you can do, then no."

Comment: I don't know if this blog is viewable without an Art of Problem Solving account, but a generalized version of this problem with a solution can be found on this blog post : http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/80001

Comment: See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/437374/43288)

Comment: See [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose that $a,b,\sqrt a+\sqrt b\in\mathbb Z$.

$(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)=a-b\in\mathbb Z$. Since $\sqrt a-\sqrt b=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt a+\sqrt b}\in\mathbb Q$. Therefore, $\sqrt a-\sqrt b$ is an algebraic integer and rational; thus, $\sqrt a-\sqrt b\in\mathbb Z$.

Next, $(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)+(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)=2\sqrt a\in\mathbb Z$ and $(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)-(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)=2\sqrt b\in\mathbb Z$. Thus, $\sqrt a$ and $\sqrt b$ are algebraic integers and rational, therefore $\sqrt a,\sqrt b\in\mathbb Z$.

Thus, $a,b,\sqrt a+\sqrt b\in\mathbb Z\Rightarrow\sqrt a,\sqrt b\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: What do you mean by "algebraic integer"? I don't understand how you went from saying that $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ is a rational to saying it is an integer.

Comment: An [Algebraic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) is a root to a polynomial with integer coefficients. An [Algebraic Integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer) is a root to a polynomial with integer coefficients with $1$ as the leading coefficient. An algebraic integer that is also rational is an integer (see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/309071)).

Comment: Ah ok thank you! I was also thinking that rather than saying $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ is an integer, you can keep saying it is rational. Since $\sqrt{a}$ is either rational (integer) or irrational, you get that it must be a whole number.

Comment: Why the downvote? When this answer was written, part of the question (including the title) was concerned with the sum of two integers. Since that is a much simpler part of the question, that is what I answered. In full generality, this question is much harder.

Answer (score 28):

At least there's an elementary way to see that if $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$ is an integer, then $a$ and $b$ are perfect squares.

Suppose $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} = c\in\mathbb{Z}.$ If $c=0$ the result is trivial. Otherwise, squaring both sides we get that
$$a + b + 2\sqrt{ab} = c^2$$
and therefore $ab$ must be a perfect square. Let's say $ab = d^2$. Then $a=\frac{d^2}{b}$ and
\begin{align*}\frac{d}{\sqrt{b}} + \sqrt{b} &= c\\
d + b &= c\sqrt{b},
\end{align*}
so $b$ is a perfect square, and $a$ must be as well.

Comment: Sadly this argument doesn't generalize in an obvious way, since squaring $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$ doesn't help. See Eric's answer for the fully general proof.

Comment: @user7530 Squaring will work for up to 4 square roots. For example, take squares on both sides of $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} = n - \sqrt{c}$.

Comment: b is a perfect square... or c is zero.

Comment: Sure. I'll add a remark.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For instance, 8 has two distinct square roots: $\sqrt 8$ and $-\sqrt 8$.  These add to zero, which is an integer.

The same thing happens with higher order roots in the complex plane. When we add the roots of a number together, we get zero. This is because they form equally distributed points on the unit circle in the complex plane, and so, if we regard them as vectors, we can readily see that they cancel out under addition.

Comment: I think this is a perfect example.  Why the downvote?

Comment: A lot of downvoting on stackexchange is just angry teenagers acting up.

Comment: If this correct answer is unsatisfying, please edit the question such that it rules out this answer and then add a helpful comment under the answer to notify me that the answer is no longer correct. I will gladly delete the answer, or edit, if possible.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer does not address the question.  The OP asked whether the statement "$a_1, \dots , a_n \in \mathbb{Z} \implies \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{a_i} \notin \mathbb{Z}$" is true or not.  Since $-\sqrt{8}$ is never the square root of an integer, your answer sheds no light on the situation.

Comment: @JavaMan That is false. $-\sqrt 8$ is one of the two square roots of $8$, which is an integer. $(-\sqrt 8)\times(-\sqrt 8) = 8$. The question, in its present form, does not rule out negative roots.

Comment: If one is to be pedantic, then I suppose you are correct.  Then again, if one was to be pedantic, the equation $\sqrt{0} + \sqrt{0} = 0$ would also seem relevant here.

Comment: @JavaMan That is incorrect. The question is worded in such a way that it rules out $\sqrt 0$, $\sqrt 1$ and $\sqrt 4$. It plainly says *"The square roots need to be irrational."*  Mathematics demands that we be pedantic.

Comment: Fair enough, and this is my last remark on the topic.  However, mathematics does not require pedantry. In fact, mathematics is often hindered by it.  Such questions have been considered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264610/why-is-abuse-of-notation-tolerated/264656#264656), for example.

Comment: When a question is tagged with `algebra-precalculus`, it is perfectly reasonable to assume that "square root" refers to the *principal* square root.

Answer (score 2):

For two summands:

$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}) = a- b$.

So either both factors are irrational or both are rational. The second case can only happen if $a$ and $b$ are perfect squares.