# Does $a^n \mid b^n$ imply $a\mid b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Does $a^n \mid b^n$ imply $a\mid b$? I think it does but haven't been able to prove it. 
I don't know much number theory so an elementary answer would be great.

Comment: Hint: Look at prime factors.

Comment: You can start with the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: [Consider this.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309023/prove-that-if-an-mid-bn-then-a-mid-b/309025#309025) Might I call yhis a duplicate? Since they end up in asking the same question.

Comment: @awllower: you're right that it's a duplicate, but I think this one has better answers.

Comment: @JavierBadia Probably because the previous one prohibited the use of GCD and UFD.

Comment: Here is a simple proof. Find $ r,s \in \mathbb{N} $ that satisfy $ \gcd(r,s) = 1 $ and $ \dfrac{b}{a} = \dfrac{s}{r} $. If $ a^{n} | b^{n} $ so that $ b^{n} = k a^{n} $ for some $ k \in \mathbb{N} $, then $ s^{n} = k r^{n} $ also. Now, we must have $ r = 1 $, otherwise $ p | r $ for some prime number $ p $, which would imply that $ p | s^{n} $ and consequently $ p | s $; it would then follow that $ \gcd(r,s) \geq p $, which contradicts our earlier assumption that $ \gcd(r,s) = 1 $. Hence, $ k = s^{n} $, which yields $ b^{n} = s^{n} a^{n} $ and consequently $ b = s a $. Therefore, $ a | b $.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can assume the fundamental theorem of arithmetic (that each integer has a unique factorization in prime numbers), you can write:
$$
\begin{align*}
a &= p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \ldots p_r^{e_r} \\
b &= q_1^{d_1} q_2^{d_2} \ldots q_s^{d_s}
\end{align*}
$$
Here the $p_i$, $q_i$ are primes, and $e_i$ and $d_i$ are all greater than 0.
If $a^n \mid b^n$, then $p_i^{n e_i}$ must have a counterpart in a $q_j^{n d_j}$, in that $p_i = q_j$ and $n e_i \le n d_j$, so it must then also be that $e_i \le d_j$; and this means $a \mid b$.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $\ $ Either examine exponents in unique prime factorizations, or, by the [Rational Root Test,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) the reduced rational root $\rm\:x = b/a\:$ of $\rm\:x^n = c\in\Bbb Z\:$ must be integral, so $\rm\:b/a\in\Bbb Z\:\Rightarrow\:a\mid b.$

Comment: @Peter For that, after cancelling any common factor, one needs only $\rm\:(a,b)=1\:\Rightarrow\:(a,b^n)=1,\:$ true by iterating Euclid's Lemma. Thus $\rm\:1 < a\nmid b^n,\:$ so $\rm\:a^n\nmid b^n.\ \ $

Comment: Yes, that was my idea. I was awfully unclear, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: $p$ is a prime factor of $k$ if and only if $p^n$ is a factor of $k^n$. This holds for any prime $p$, integer $k$, and positive integer $n$.