# Prove or disprove $a^2\mid b^3\Longrightarrow a\mid b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I need to prove or to give a counter-example:

> $$a^2\mid b^3\Longrightarrow a\mid b$$

**My attempt:**

First, let's check with small integres,trying to find counter-example:

$2^2\mid 6^3\Longrightarrow 2\mid 6\\
1^2\mid 2^3\Longrightarrow 1\mid 2$

it looks correct,let's try to prove it:

$$a^2\mid b^3\Longrightarrow k \cdot a^2=b^3\Longrightarrow k \cdot aa=bbb\\$$

here I'm stuck

I don't know if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236862/prove-or-disprove-a3-mid-b2-rightarrow-a-mid-b) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351623/does-an-mid-bn-imply-a-mid-b) related because here it's different

Comment: Hint: what would happen if you had $a^2=b^3$?

Comment: @Wojowu then $a,b=1$ or $a,b=0$?

Comment: Nope, there actually are nontrivial examples. Try to look for one.

Comment: @Wojowu $a=27$ and $b=9$

Comment: What does it tell you about the statement you tried to prove?

Comment: Ok, I got it thank you

Comment: Or $a=8$, $b=4$, for an example with smaller numbers..

Comment: Or $a=1000$ and $b=100$, then both $a^2$ and $b^3$ is $1000000$, but $a$ is greater than $b$, hence cannot divide it.