# It seems to overlap with other content.

Tags: integers

It seems to overlap with other content. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If the sum is an integer, what does that tell you about the denominators?

Comment: @BillDubuque Let's call them $x$ and $y$. $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \frac{p}{q}$, with $\gcd (p,q) = 1$. $y = \lceil y\rceil - \frac{r}{s}$ with $\gcd(r,s) = 1$. $x+y \in \mathbb{Z}$ implies $d := \frac{p}{q} - \frac{r}{s} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $0 \leqslant \frac{p}{q} < 1$ and $0 \leqslant \frac{r}{s} < 1$, it follows that $-1 < d < 1$. Which means $\frac{p}{q} = \frac{r}{s}$.

Comment: @BillDubuque $(d\in\mathbb{Z} \land -1 < d < 1) \implies (d = 0)$. $\frac{p}{q} - \frac{r}{s} = 0 \iff \frac{p}{q} = \frac{r}{s}$. Then we deduce $(p = r) \land (q = s)$ from $\gcd(p,q) = 1 = \gcd(r,s)$.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, now it is clear which proof you intend. It essentially invokes the uniqueness of least terms representations of fractions - what I call **unique fractionization**. This is equivalent to unique factorization, Euclid's Lemma, etc. Many of my [prior posts](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+%22unique+fractionization%22) discuss this further. Given that approach, one can skip your reduction to proper fractions and proceed directly as follows, where the second line of the proof has essentially inlined a proof of unique fractionizaton.

Comment: $\dfrac{a}b=n-\dfrac{c}d=\dfrac{nd-c}d=:\dfrac{\bar c}d\ $ and $\ \color{#0a0}{(b,a)}=1=(d,c)\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{(d,\bar c)}=(d,nd\!-\!c)=(d,c)=1.\  $ 
So $\,ad = \bar cb^{\phantom{I^I}}\!\!\!\!,\,$ by EL = Euclid's Lemma  $\ \color{#0a0}{b\mid a}\,d\,\Rightarrow\, b\mid d,\ $ and $\,\ \color{#c00}{d\mid \bar c}\,b\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid b,\,$ hence $\ \color{#c0d}{b = d}.\\ $

Therefore $\ \dfrac{a}b\dfrac{c}d\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\,b\mid ac\,\Rightarrow\,b=1\,$ by $\,\color{}{(b,a)}=1=\color{}{\color{#b0d}{(b,c)=(d,c)}},\,$ and EL. $\ $ **QED** $\ \ $

Comment: @Daniel See my answer for a more direct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p,q$ be rational. Then $p+q=n\in\mathbb{Z}\implies p=n-q$. So let $\displaystyle q=\frac{a}{b}$ be in lowest terms. We then have $(n-\frac{a}{b})\frac{a}{b}=m\in\mathbb{Z}\implies na-\frac{a^2}{b}=mb\implies\frac{a^2}{b}\in\mathbb{Z}\implies \frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Z}$ since $\frac{a}{b}$ are coprime. So $q$, hence also $p$ are integers.

Comment: This is essentially the common proof of the Rational Root Test, specialized to the case of a monic quadratic polynomial, here $\, (x-p)(x-q)\, =\, x^2-(p+q)x + pq \in \Bbb Z[x].\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Maybe, but I don't see the motivation behind looking at that polynomial.

Comment: It is this: $\,p+q\,$ and $\,pq\,$ are both integers iff $\,f(x) = (x-p)(x-q)$ has integer coefficients. By RRT, we know that rational roots of such a monic polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ must be integral. The conceptual foundations will be clearer when one learns about *algebraic* integers.

Answer (score 13):

This may not be the simplest proof, but I think it's pretty.  Let your two rational numbers be $r,s$.  Then the polynomial $f(x)=(x-r)(x-s)=x^2-(r+s)x+rs$ has integer coefficients by your hypotheses.  By [Gauss' Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29), this polynomial must be reducible over the integers, and hence $r,s$ are both integers.

Comment: You dropped an $x$ in the polynomial.

Comment: @user2357112 You used the wrong article.

Comment: @Awesome: No, $x$ starts with a vowel sound, even though the letter is a consonant.

Comment: @user2357112 Well there can be a debate.

Comment: @Awesome [No there cannot](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/) (unless how you pronounces *x* doesn't start with a vowel sound, but then I think we're outside English so, a/an is irrelevant.)

Comment: Okay.$ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Awesome this really isn't a place to write a comment to correct a minor spelling mistake (and I don't think it was a mistake)
vadim123 very nice proof!

Answer (score 2):

By plugging in $x=a$ and $x=b$, we see that
$$
x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0
$$
As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309071), a rational root of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients must be an integer.

---

**Importing the Referenced Answer**

It has been suggested that specializing the proof in the above referenced answer to quadratic polynomials might be useful.

Suppose $x=\frac pq$, where $ps+qr=1$, is a root of $x^2+mx+n=0$, where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Subsitute $x=\frac{1-qr}{qs}$
$$
\frac{(1-qr)^2}{q^2s^2}+m\frac{1-qr}{qs}+n=0
$$
Multiply by $pqs^2$
$$
\left(\frac pq-2pr+pqr^2\right)+pms(1-qr)+npqs^2=0
$$
cancelling yields
$$
\frac pq=2pr-pqr^2+pms(qr-1)-npqs^2
$$
In particular, $x=\frac pq\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Above is a perfect opportunity to specialize your linked Bezout-based proof to the quadratic case, which should prove more comprehensible than the general proof. Adding that above would be nice. With your new $\rm 100K$ powered Bezouka, can you Bezoutify  the $1$-line proof in my answer? Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the equation provided by Vadim above, $x^2-(r+s)x + rs=0$, take any rational root $a/b$, with $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  We get, after clearing the denominator:
$a^2 -b(r+s)x +rsb^2=0$,which can be rewritten to show  $a^2$ is a multiple of $b$ which contradicts the fact that $a$ and $b$ are co-prime. (This is essentially the proof that a rational number that is an algebraic integer is an integer, for the quadratic case).

Comment: Yes, that is just the common proof of the [Rational Root Test,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) specialized to the case of a monic quadratic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

$\underbrace{\dfrac{a}b\!+\!\dfrac{c}d}_{\large (a,b)\,=\,1}\! =n\in\Bbb Z,\ \dfrac{a}b\not\in\Bbb Z\overset{\large \exists\, p\ {\rm prime}}\Rightarrow$  $\begin{array}{}p\nmid a\\ p\mid b\end{array}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,\dfrac{a}b\dfrac{c}d = \dfrac{a}b\!\!\!\dfrac{\,(bn\!-\!a)}{b}\!\not\in\Bbb Z\,$ by $\,\begin{array}{} p\nmid a,\, bn\!-\!a\\ p\mid b\end{array}\ $ **QED**