# Prove that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt 3}$ is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, radicals, rationality-testing

Prove that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$ is irrational. I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Suppose it is rational.  What expressions does this assumption lead to?

Comment: You will need to use a proof by contradiction.

Comment: "I can't seem to figure this one out." Which *other ones* can you *figure out*?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $x\in \mathbb{Q} \implies x^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: (+1) However, one needs to know that $\sqrt3\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$ satisfies $x^4-4x^2+1=0$, which means that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}$ is an [algebraic integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer).

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309071), if $x$ is an algebraic integer, then $x\in\mathbb{Q}\implies x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $1\lt\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}\lt2$, $\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}\not\in\mathbb{Z}$; therefore, $\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.