# Prove that if $x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dots + a_0 = 0$ for some integers $a_{n-1}, \dots, a_0$, then $x$ is irrational unless $x$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

This is an exercise from Spivak's "Calculus" 4th edition.

> 18.a. Prove that if $x$ satisfies
> $$x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dots + a_0 = 0$$
> for some integers $a_{n-1}, \dots, a_0$, then $x$ is irrational unless $x$ is an integer.

The solution is given as

> Suppose $x = p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are natural numbers with no common factor. Then
> $$\frac{p^n}{q^n} + a_{n-1}\frac{p^{n-1}}{q^{n-1}}+ \dots + a_0 = 0$$, so
> $$\tag{*} p^n + a_{n-1}p^{n-1}q + \dots + a_0 q^n = 0$$
> Now if $q \neq \pm 1$, then $q$ has some prime number as a factor. This prime factor divides every term of (*) other than $p^n$, **so it must divide $p^n$ also. Therefore it divides $p$**, a contradiction. So $q = \pm 1$, which means that $x$ is an integer.

I am confused about the conclusions in bold above. How does every other term of (*) being divisible by the prime factor affect $p^n$? Also, I've been struggling to prove that if $k$ is prime and $k|p^n$, then $k|p$, which seems to be the lemma used above.

Comment: $p^n =- a_{n-1}p^{n-1}q - \dots - a_0 q^n$ and that factor of $q$ divides every term on the right-hand side. – See also [“rational root theorem”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! That makes sense now.

Comment: Great, elegant solution!

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the bar notation, to my understanding it means, if k divides pⁿ then k also divides p?

Comment: @AshWhole Yes, that is correct.

Comment: This might be answered in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309071).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every other terms has a $q$ factor explicitly besides $p^n$.

Since $$p^n = -q(a_{n-1}p^{n-1} + \ldots + a_0q^{n-1})$$

Hence $q$ must divide $p^n$.

As for your second quesiton, let a prime factor of $q$ be  $q_0$. Consider the prime factorization of $p=\prod_{i=1}^m q_i^{r_i} $, then $p^n=\prod_{i=1}^{m} q_i^{nr_i} $, if $q_0$ divide $p^n$ is a prime, then $q_0$ must be one of the $q_i$ with positive $r_i$ power. Hence $q_0$ divide $p$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is there a more formal argument for the second question? I don't think that $p$ has to be prime in this case. It was given as a natural number.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the second part now.