# Unique factorisation in ring generated by square roots of prime numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Let $\langle\sqrt{\mathbb{N}}\rangle=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5,\ldots]$ denote the ring generated by the square roots of all prime numbers. Is it it known whether $\langle\sqrt{\mathbb{N}}\rangle$ is a unique factorisation domain?

It seems hard to determine so because I can't think think of a 'norm-function' as we do have in 'finite' extensions of $\mathbb Z$, such as $\mathbb Z[\sqrt2]$.

Comment: Does it help: $(1+\sqrt{2})(-1+\sqrt{2})=1=(2+\sqrt{5})(-2+\sqrt{5})$ or $(1+\sqrt{3})(-1+\sqrt{3})=2=(2+\sqrt{6})(-2+\sqrt{6})$?

Comment: The first example you give are just units and their inverse so that doesn't exclude unique factorisation. I'm not sure about the second, I'll check.

Comment: For any $a\in {\mathbb Z}$ one has, for instance, $(a+1-\sqrt{a^2+a+1})(a+1+\sqrt{a^2+a+1})=a$ and $a=(a+2-\sqrt{a^2+3a+4})(a+2+\sqrt{a^2+3a+4})$. Does it mean that any $0\ne a\in {\mathbb Z}$ is a unit?

Comment: What I wanted to say is that perhaps $a+1+\sqrt{a^2+a+1}$ and $a+2+\sqrt{a^2+3a+4}$ are unique up to a unit. But I doubt they are.

Comment: Is this ring even Noetherian (i.e. are we even guaranteed factorizations into irreducibles, let alone unique such).

Comment: @user26857 Sure, but if it is not noetherian, then it might be more natural to look for elements that do not factor into irreducibles before we look for ones with different factorizations.

Comment: In the factorization $(1+\sqrt{3})(−1+\sqrt{3})=2=(2+\sqrt{6})(−2+\sqrt{6})$, if $1+\sqrt{3}$ and $2+\sqrt{6}$ equal up to a unit, the $\frac{2+\sqrt{6}}{1+\sqrt{3}}=-1+\sqrt{3}+\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{6}$ should be a unit. Is it?

Comment: @JankoBracic It isn't even contained in $\langle\sqrt{\mathbb N}\rangle$. Neither is $\frac{2+\sqrt{6}}{1-\sqrt{3}}$ so I think you have found us a counterexample. (Note that we need the fact that the representation of elements in $\langle\sqrt{\mathbb Q}\rangle$ is unique in some sense; Hagen von Eitzen gave a proof for that [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/437374/43288).)