# Prove that $\sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{5}+ \sqrt{7}$ is irrational

Tags: radicals, rationality-testing

> How can I prove that $\sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{5}+ \sqrt{7}$ is irrational?

I know that $\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{7}$ are all irrational and that $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$, $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}$, $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}$ are all irrational, too. But how can I prove that $\sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{5}+ \sqrt{7}$ is irrational?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can learn how to write your formulae in LaTeX, to make them look nicer, for your next questions. :)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/437374/43288 for a more general result.

Answer (score 14):

Suppose $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7} = r$ for some rational $r$. Then, $$(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^2 = (r-\sqrt{7})^2 \implies 8+2\sqrt{15} = 7+r^2-2r\sqrt{7}$$
So, $$1-r^2+2\sqrt{15} =-2r\sqrt{7}$$
Let $1-r^2 = k$, which will be a rational number. So,
$$(k+2\sqrt{15})^2 = k^2+ 60+4k\sqrt{15} = 28r^2$$
The LHS is irrational while the RHS is rational. Hence, we have a contradiction.

Comment: I generalized your solution and made it into a question (with attribution): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203190/find-conditions-on-positive-integers-so-that-sqrta-sqrtb-sqrtc-is-irr

Answer (score 6):

You can easily show (probably you have already done so) $\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7} \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7})$.

If your sum would be rational, we would deduce $\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7} \in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}) \subset \mathbb Q(\sqrt{3})$, clearly a contradiction.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\alpha=\sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{5}+ \sqrt{7}$.

Then $\alpha$ is a root of $x^8-60 x^6+782 x^4-3180 x^2+3481=0$.
Since this is a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, the rational root theorem tells you that $\alpha$ is either irrational or an integer.

Now

$\quad 1.7 < \sqrt 3 < 1.8 $

$\quad 2.2 < \sqrt 5 < 2.3 $

$\quad 2.6 < \sqrt 7 < 2.7 $

gives

$\quad 6.5 < \alpha < 6.8 $

which proves that $\alpha$ is not an integer.

We can avoid even these fine estimates: if $\alpha$ is an integer then it must divide $3481=59^2$, but clearly $1 < \alpha < 3\sqrt 7 < 9 < 59 $.

Answer (score 4):

Assume $$\sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{5}+ \sqrt{7}= \frac{a}{b}$$ for some integers $a,b$. Multiblying both sides by $\sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{5}- \sqrt{7}$ yields $$ (\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^2 - 7 = \frac{a(\sqrt{3}+ \sqrt{5}- \sqrt{7})}{b}=\frac{a\left(a/b-2\sqrt{7}\right)}{b} \\ 2\sqrt{15}+8-7=\frac{a^2/b-2a\sqrt{7}}{b} \\ 2b\sqrt{15} = \frac{a^2}{b}-2a\sqrt{7}-b \\ 60b^2=\frac{a^4}{b^2}+28a^2+b^2-\frac{4a^3\sqrt{7}}{b}+4ab\sqrt{7}-2a^2 \\ 59b^2-26a^2-\frac{a^4}{b^2}=4a\sqrt{7}\left(b-\frac{a^2}{b}\right). $$ We can divide both sides by $4a(b^2−a^2)=4a(b-a)(b+a)$ because $a$ can't be $0$ by definition, $b+a$ is a positive integer and $b−a$ can't be $0$ because that would imply $a/b=1$, which is impossible. Thus we get $$\frac{b\left(59b^4-26a^2b^2-a^4\right)}{4a(b^2-a^2)}=\sqrt{7},$$ contradiction.

Comment: Contradiction only if the numerator and the denominator of that last fraction are not zero...

Comment: If that last fraction is undefined, then the RHS is too, but it isn't; why wouldn't that be a contradiction anyway?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you only have ${b\left(59b^4-26a^2b^2-a^4\right)}=\sqrt{7}\cdot{4a(b^2-a^2)}$

Comment: We can divide both sides by $4a(b^2-a^2)$ because $a$ can't be $0$ by definition, $b+a$ is a positive integer and $b-a$ can't be $0$ because that would imply $a/b=1$, which is impossible. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's much better. Consider adding this to your answer.

Comment: @lhf I see, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to Galois, if $\sqrt3 +\sqrt5+\sqrt7$ is rational, then it must be invariant after changing the sign of any or all of the square roots. But the expression is clearly positive, so it cannot be equal to its negative.

Comment: Please clarify.  $\sqrt{4}$ is rational, but we generally don't say $\sqrt{4} = -\sqrt{4}$.

Comment: In this case, the Galois transformations involve changing the signs of any or all of the roots of the three primes. Total of eight transformations, including unity. Your suggestion is not included.