# $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, radicals, rationality-testing

> Prove that $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$ is irrational

My attempt:-
    Suppose $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$ is rational, then for some $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have $$\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}=x$$
Rewriting this equation as $$\sqrt{6}-x=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$$
and now squaring this we get $$ 6-2x\sqrt{6}+x^2=5+2\sqrt{6}$$. This implies that $$\sqrt{6}=\frac{x^2-1}{2+2x}$$ but this is absurd as RHS of the above equation is rational but we know that $\sqrt6$ is irrational. Therefore , $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. Does this look good? Have I written it properly? Is there any other proof besides this..like one using geometry? Thank you.

Comment: It looks good to me. By the way , shouldn't the question be to prove $\sqrt6 - \sqrt2 -\sqrt3 $ is irrational

Comment: I think you need to prove $x \neq 1$

Comment: @The Demonix_Hermit , Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @David, I think not..as  $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}\lt 0$

Comment: $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}=(\sqrt{3}-1)(\sqrt{2}-1)-1$ which is clearly less than zero.

Comment: @HVxvejjw Good point! I think we can also go to the second-to-last expression and easily check there that indeed $x \neq 1$, then go on with the next step

Comment: @David, see Robert Z's  answer belwo..I made a mistake in the last step. Although my above comment proves that the original expression is negative, I still have to prove that $x\not=-1$.

Comment: For a somewhat stronger result, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96946/how-to-prove-1-sqrt2-sqrt3-and-sqrt6-are-linearly-independent-ove).

Comment: @Robert Israel, Thanks a lot for sharing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$ is a root of $x^4 - 22 x^2 - 48 x - 23$.

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$  is either irrational or an integer.

But
$$
1.4 < \sqrt 2 < 1.5
\\
1.7 < \sqrt 3 < 1.8
\\
2.4 < \sqrt 6 < 2.5
\\
$$
imply
$$
-0.9 < \sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3} <-0.6
$$
and so $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$ is not an integer. Therefore, it is irrational.

Comment: Very nice . Thank you.

Comment: See also the last part of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1203120/589 for a slightly different take.

Answer (score 12):

In your proof, after $6-2x\sqrt{6}+x^2=5+2\sqrt{6}$ we have that
$$x^2+1=2(x+1)\sqrt{6}$$
If $x=-1$ then, from the above equation, it follows that $2=0$. Therefore $x$ is a rational number different from $-1$. After dividing by $2(x+1)\not=0$ we get
$$\sqrt{6}=\frac{x^2+1}{2(x+1)}\in \mathbb{Q}.$$
Contradiction! Hence $x=\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$ is not a rational number.

Comment: @HVxvejjw In your proof it should be  $\sqrt{6}=\frac{x^2+1}{2(x+1)}$

Comment: ,oh yes. Thanks for pointing out. Thanks a lot.