# sum of reciprocals of square roots cannot be an integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

Show that the sum
$$ S = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$
cannot be an integer for any value of $n$. I am completely stumped any help would be welcome.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: See e.g. Hagen von Eitzen's solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437350/the-sum-of-square-roots-of-non-perfect-squares-is-never-integer/437374#437374)