# Let $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7})$. Find $\gamma \in E$ such that $E = \mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$

Tags: galois-theory

As given in the title. Let $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{7})$. Find $\gamma \in E$ such that $E = \mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$.

I am not really sure where to start. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You  could try $\sqrt2+\sqrt5+\sqrt7$.

Comment: Try $\gamma=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{7}$

Comment: Ok I did think it might be something like that but wasn't sure if that was too simple.

Comment: I suppose I now need to show that I can get $\sqrt(2), \sqrt(5), \sqrt(7)$ from this linear combination?

Comment: And if so, how do I show this since I can't use the usual conjugate trick

Comment: The powers of $a=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{7}$ can be written as $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combinations of $1, \sqrt{2},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7}$ and their pairwise products. Then $1,a,a^2,...,a^6$ give you a system of equations expressing $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{7}$ in terms of those powers of $a$. You just need to show that the determinant is non-singular.

Comment: Linking a number of related threads [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306082/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/442259/11619), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619),[4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93453/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to fear that things could get messy when squaring $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 5 + \sqrt 7$, and all the more so when trying to generalize to arbitrary sums of square roots of primes. A less computational solution consists in using a bit of Kummer theory to deal only with the multiplicative structure, but since I don't know of your background, let me try to start from scratch (without being too messy). Preliminary observation : any quadratic extension of a field $F$ of characteristic $\neq 2$ is of the form $F(\sqrt a)$, with $a \in F^*$, $\notin {F^*}^2$, but actually $F(\sqrt a)$ depends only on the class $\bar a \in F^*/{F^*}^2$. It will be convenient in the sequel to view the group $F^*/{F^*}^2$ as a vector space over the finite field $\mathbf F_2$.

We want to prove by induction the property ($P_n$) : For $n \ge 2$, let $p_1, ..., p_n$ be $n$ pairwise distinct primes. Then the following assertions are valid : $(i_n)$ The extension $K_n:=\mathbf Q (\sqrt p_1,...,\sqrt p_n)$ is normal, with Galois group $\cong (\mathbf Z/2)^n$ ;  $(ii_n)$ The subspace $V_n$ of $\mathbf Q^*/{\mathbf Q^*}^2$ generated by $\bar p_1,..., \bar p_n$ has $\mathbf F_2$-dimension $n$; $(iii_n)$ $K_n=\mathbf Q(\sqrt p_1+...+\sqrt p_n)$. Suppose that ($P_n$) holds and let us show that ($P_{n+1}$) holds:

$(i_{n+1})$ It suffices to show that $\sqrt p_{n+1} \notin K_n$. But the $2^n-1$ quadratic subextensions of $K_n$ are all of the form $\mathbf Q(\sqrt q)$, where $q$ is a product $p_{i_1}...p_{i_k}$, and $\mathbf Q(\sqrt q)=\mathbf Q(\sqrt p_{n+1})$ iff $q^{-1}p_{n+1} \in {\mathbf Q^*}^2$, but this is impossible since the primes $p_1,..., p_{n+1}$ are pairwise distinct

$(ii_{n+1})$ See the end of the proof of $(i_{n+1})$

$(iii_{n+1})$ By $(i_{n+1})$, the extension $K_{n+1}=K_n (\sqrt p_{n+1})$ is quadratic over $K_n$, and the element $(\sqrt p_1+...+\sqrt p_n)+\sqrt p_{n+1}$ of $K_{n+1}$ does not belong to $K_n$

It remains to prove ($P_2$), but in fact we have only to repeat the arguments already used in the recurrence.

NB: The 3 assertions in ($P_n$) are actually equivalent. The equivalence between $(i_n)$ and $(ii_n)$ is a straightforward consequence of Kummer theory. Logically speaking, we could have dispensed with the assertion $(ii_n)$, but it has the merit to show that only the multiplicative structure comes into play.