# Is any set of distinct "reduced" roots linearly independent over the rationals?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots

**Definition:** let $n, a \in \mathbb{N}$. The root $\sqrt[n]{a}$ is *reducible* if it can be written as $\sqrt[m]{b}$ for some natural numbers  $b$ and $m<n$, or if it can be written as $M\sqrt[n]{c}$ for naturals $M$ and $c<a$. Otherwise we say the root is *reduced*.

The condition that the roots be reduced is necessary to prevent cases such as

$$\sqrt{4}-\sqrt[4]{16}$$

or as

$$\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[4]{4}$$

---

**Conjecture:** a set of distinct reduced roots is linearly independent over the rationals. In other words,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n M_k\sqrt[N_k]a_k\notin \mathbb{Q}$$

for any rationals $M_k≠0$ and naturals $N_k, a_k$ such that the roots $\sqrt[N_k]{a_k}$ are distinct and reduced.

---

**Is the conjecture above true?**

---

The condition is sufficient to show that a pair of roots is independent over the rationals:

**Lemma:** any root $\sqrt[n]{a}$ is either irrational or an integer.

**Theorem:** let $\sqrt[n]{a}$ and $\sqrt[m]{b}$ be different reduced roots. Then $\sqrt[n]{a}$ and $\sqrt[m]{b}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

*Proof:* suppose without loss of generality that $n\leq m$. It is sufficient to show that $\sqrt[m]{b}/\sqrt[n]{a}$ is irrational. Suppose not, then

$$\frac{\sqrt[m]{b}}{\sqrt[n]{a}}=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}$$

If the expression was equal to an integer $k$ then $\sqrt[m]{b}=k\sqrt[n]{a}$ and the root $\sqrt[m]{b}$ wouldn't be reduced, contrary to hypothesis. Now choose $p,q$ so that these share no common divisors larger than $1$ and $q>1$. Then

$$\sqrt[m]{b^n}=\frac{p^n}{q^n}a$$

where the expression belongs in $\mathbb{Z}$ by **lemma 1**. Any prime that divides $q$ cannot divide $p$, since we have chosen these to have no common divisors. Thus $q^n$ must divide $a$. We have $q^nz=a$ for some positive integer $z$ and $q\sqrt[n]{z}=\sqrt[n]{a}$ with $q>1$ so that the root $\sqrt[n]{a}$ is not reduced, contrary to hypothesis. $\blacksquare$

---

Perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30687/the-square-roots-of-different-primes-are-linearly-independent-over-the-field-of) is worth including.

Comment: The conjecture holds for arbitrarily many square roots, since then you are just considering $\sqrt d$ for $d$ a square-free integer. The $\mathbb Q$-vector space $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p_1},\dots,\sqrt{p_n})$, where the $p_i$ are distinct primes, has dimension $2^n$, and has basis all products of subsets of the $p_i$. Thus they are linearly independent.

Comment: More related threads [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2014190/11619). The square roots are, perhaps disproportionately, well represented in the discussion around this theme. Apart being the obvious choice for the first case they generate Galois extensions and we have more machinery to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is true (or if not true as stated, some small correction to it is true). I don't have a proof, I think the general case probably relies on being a bit more clever with roots of unity / Lagrange resolvents / representation theory. But here is a proof for the case of square and cube (and therefore sixth) roots.

First, as noted in the comments:

**Fact 1**. The extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{p_n})$, for distinct primes $p_i$, has degree $2^d$ and basis given by all products of square roots of subsets of the $p_i$. Actually a slightly more detailed statement is: the lattice of subfields is the lattice of subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$.

Proof: This is obvious for $n=1$. In general, suppose $\sqrt{p_n} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{p_{n-1}})$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p_n}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d_i})$ for one of the quadratic subfields (listed according to the lattice description above). So it's enough to show:

**Fact 2**. For all distinct squarefree integers $d, d'$. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \ne \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d'})$.

Proof. Suppose $\sqrt{d'} = a + b \sqrt{d}$. Apply the non-identity Galois automorphism. This can't fix $\sqrt{d'}$ since it's not rational, so it takes it to the other root and gives $-\sqrt{d'} = a - b \sqrt{d}$. Subtracting gives $2\sqrt{d'} = 2b \sqrt{d}$. This is a contradiction since $d'$ is squarefree.

I wrote out those proofs even though they're pretty standard, because I'm going to generalize them to the cubic case. I think the general case is probably along the same lines.

First let $K_2 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p} : p \text{ prime or } -1)$. Every finite subfield has degree $2^d$ and a lattice of subfields isomorphic to the lattice of subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^d$. (Adjoin $i$ last to go from a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ to a complex field.) Also, observe that $K_2$ contains the cube roots of unity $\zeta_3 = \tfrac{1}{2}(1 + i\sqrt{3})$.

Below, $\sqrt[3]{d}$ always refers to the real cube root.

**Fact 3**. Let $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and let $K$ be any field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing the cube roots of unity. Then $x^3 - d$ is irreducible or splits completely over $K$. In particular, $[K(\sqrt[3]{d}) : K]$ is $1$ or $3$.

Proof: If the polynomial factors, it has a root since it's degree $3$. So, we get the other roots too using the cube roots of unity. (This is one place where my argument is easier for cube roots!).

Now we can prove:

**Theorem**. For any distinct primes $p_1, \ldots, p_n$, $K_2(\sqrt[3]{p_1}, \ldots, \sqrt[3]{p_n})$ has degree $3^d$ and a lattice of subfields isomorphic to the lattice of subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^n$. In particular:

- It has a $K_2$-basis given by $\{\sqrt[3]{d}\}$ where $d = p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_n^{k_n}$ with $0 \leq k_n \leq 2$. (These are all "reduced roots" in the sense you were defining, involving at most cube roots anyway.)
- The only degree-3 sub-extensions are of the form $K_2(\sqrt[3]{d})$ for some $d$ as above.

Proof: For $n=1$, by Fact 3 it's enough to show that $\sqrt[3]{d} \notin K_2$. But if this were true, then $\sqrt[3]{d}$ would be in a finite subfield of $K_2$, and those all have degrees given by powers of $2$, a contradiction.

For $n \geq 2$, suppose $\sqrt[3]{p_n} \in K_2(\sqrt[3]{p_1}, \ldots, \sqrt[3]{p_{n-1}})$. Then $K_2(\sqrt[3]{p_n}) = K_2(\sqrt[3]{d})$ for $d$ one of the integers described above. So it's enough to show that this doesn't happen -- in other words we're reducing to the case $n=2$.

**Fact 4**. If $d, d'$ are distinct integers of the form $p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_n^{k_n}$ with $0 \leq k_i \leq 2$, then $K_2(\sqrt[3]{d}) \ne K_2(\sqrt[3]{d'})$ unless the vectors $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{k}'$, viewed as elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^n$, generate the same subgroup. (Note that this exception doesn't occur above since $p_n$ is the new prime and $d$ isn't divisible by it at all.)

Proof: Similar to the Galois trick above. The extension is Galois since $K_2$ contains the cube roots of unity. Suppose
$$\sqrt[3]{d'} = a + b \sqrt[3]{d} + c (\sqrt[3]{d})^2$$
for some $a,b,c \in K_2$. Apply the Galois automorphism sending $\sqrt[3]{d} \mapsto \zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{d}$. This can't fix $\sqrt[3]{d'}$ since, as noted above, $\sqrt[3]{d'} \notin K_2$. So we get
$$\begin{align*} \zeta_3^\epsilon \sqrt[3]{d'} &= a + b \zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{d} + c \zeta_3^2 (\sqrt[3]{d})^2 \\ \zeta_3^{2\epsilon}\sqrt[3]{d'} &= a + b \zeta_3^2 \sqrt[3]{d} + c \zeta_3 (\sqrt[3]{d})^2, \end{align*}$$
where $\epsilon$ is either $1$ or $2$. Divide out the $\zeta_3^\epsilon$ and $\zeta_3^{2\epsilon}$ factors and add up all three equations to get
$$3\sqrt[3]{d'} = (1 + \zeta_3^{2\epsilon} + \zeta_3^\epsilon)a + (1 + \zeta_3^{1+2\epsilon} + \zeta_3^{2+\epsilon})b\sqrt[3]{d} + (1 + \zeta_3^{2+2\epsilon} + \zeta_3^{1+\epsilon})c(\sqrt[3]{d})^2.$$
If $\epsilon = 1$, this says $$3\sqrt[3]{d'} = 3b \sqrt[3]{d}.$$
If $\epsilon = -1$, it instead says $$3\sqrt[3]{d'} = 3c (\sqrt[3]{d})^2.$$
So $d' = b^3 d$ or $d' = c^3 d^2$. So $b$ or $c$ is the cube root of a rational number, and since $b, c \in K_2$, the only possibility here is for them $b$ or $c$ to be a rational number times a cube root of unity. Since we used positive real cube roots, we can assume $b, c$ are actually rational and positive. Then by examining prime factorizations, we see that the exponent vectors of $d$ and $d'$ span the same subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is indeed true. Suppose that we have an identity

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m M_i\sqrt[N_i]{a_i} = 0 \tag{1}
$$

where the $M_i (1\leq i \leq m)$ are rational numbers, the $a_i$ are positive integers and the roots $r_i=\sqrt[N_i]{a_i}$ are distinct and reduced (note that $1=\sqrt[1]{1}$ is itself a reduced root). Denote by $p_1 \lt p_2 \lt \ldots \lt p_k$ the prime appearing in the factorization of some $a_i$. Then for each $i$, we have (nonnegative, rational) exponents $e_{i,1},\ldots,e_{i,n}$ such that $r_i=p_1^{e_{i,1}}\ldots p_1^{e_{i,n}}$ with $0\leq e_{i,n} \lt 1$ (because $r_i$ is reduced) and the uples $(e_{i,1},\ldots,e_{i,n})$ are pairwise distinct (because the $r_i$ are distinct).

Denote by $N$ the least common multiple of the $N_i$ ; then for each $i$ and $j$, the denominator of $e_{i,j}$ divides $N_i$ which in turn divides $N$. So $g_{i,j}=Ne_{i,j}$ is an integer, and we have $0 \leq g_{i,j} \lt N$. Then
(1) can be rewritten as

$$
\sum_{i=1}^m M_i\alpha_1^{g_{i,1}}\alpha_2^{g_{i,2}}\ldots\alpha_n^{g_{i,n}} = 0 \tag{2}
$$

where $\alpha_i=\sqrt[N]{p_i}$  for $1\leq i \leq m$.

But by Besicovich' result (which is also the subject of an older [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150141/linear-independence-of-roots-over-q))
we have $[{\mathbb Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n):{\mathbb Q}]=N^n$, so all the $M_i$ must be zero in (2), which finishes the proof.