# Showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{7}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[3]{7})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> How can I show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{7}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[3]{7})$?

I tried:

$\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[3]{7} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{7}) \Rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[3]{7}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{7})$

For the other direction I get:

$(\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[3]{7})^3=12+(\sqrt[3]{5})^2\sqrt[3]{7}+2(\sqrt[3]{5})^2\sqrt[3]{7}+2\sqrt[3]{5}(\sqrt[3]{7})^2+(\sqrt[3]{7})^2\sqrt[3]{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}+\sqrt[3]{7})$

Now I don't know what to do next.

How to continue to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5},\sqrt[3]{7}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt[3]{7})$?

Comment: This holds the same way as for square roots in general, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668539/to-show-that-mathbf-q-sqrtrp-1-ldots-sqrtrp-n-mathbf-q-sqrtr?rq=1). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014190/prove-that-mathbbq-sqrtrp-1-cdots-sqrtrp-n-mathbbq-rn/2015336#2015336).

Comment: I don't see how to transform this to get the inclusion here. My idea was to write the equation in terms of $\sqrt[3]{5}$, but it doesn't work properly.