# To show $Q(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q})= Q(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})$, where p and q are prime with gcd 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

One-sided containment is clear i.e. $Q(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}) \supseteq Q(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})$. To show other side I tried in this manner,
suppose $p > q$ then $\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q} \in Q(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})$ implies $({\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q}})^{-1} = \frac{\sqrt{p} - \sqrt{q}}{p-q} \in Q(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})$ implies $\sqrt{p} - \sqrt{q} \in Q(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})$.
Hence $\sqrt{p} = \frac{1}{2}((\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})+(\sqrt{p} -\sqrt{q})) \in Q(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})$. Similiarly $\sqrt{q} \in Q(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})$. From here we get $Q(\sqrt{p}, \sqrt{q}) \subseteq Q(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})$.

I am not sure that it is correct or not, please tell me if any problem with my proof.

Comment: That's quite a clever argument....

Comment: See also [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93453/how-to-prove-that-mathbbq-sqrtp-1-sqrtp-2-ldots-sqrtp-n-mat?rq=1), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668539/to-show-that-mathbf-q-sqrtrp-1-ldots-sqrtrp-n-mathbf-q-sqrtr?rq=1). Where did you use that $\gcd(p,q)=1$?

Comment: Since gcd(p,q)=1, it means they are not same prime so the quotient $ \frac{p-q}{\sqrt{p} - \sqrt{q}}$ is well defined.

Comment: I do not think that $\sqrt{p} = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{p} + \sqrt{q})(\sqrt{p} -\sqrt{q}) $ is correct. And it is highly unususal to state that $gcd(p,q)=1$, in addition, the statement $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p},\sqrt{q})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})$ is true for *any* pair of primes, irrespective if they are different or not.

Comment: The proof (after correcting typos) seems to work for any distinct positive integers $p$ and $q$, and the result is obvious when $p=q$.

Comment: Thanx, there was + instead of the product. - edited

Comment: You have the expression for $(\sqrt{p}+\sqrt{q})^{-1}$ upside down.

Comment: Yes, it's well known, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/93469/242) for background

Comment: @DerekHolt thanx, noticed it.....-corrected