# Is the extension $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}) $ simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Intuitively, it is not.

Can anyone give a proof?

Comment: See also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/93453/11619) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1575646/11619) for related questions this is a special case of..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *actually is*, and the same can be said of any finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ per the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem), which is indeed unintuitive and surprising.  In other words, there does exist a $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\beta) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.  To find such a $\beta$, we can take advantage of the following lemma:

---

**Lemma**: If $K/F$ is a Galois extension, then the minimal polynomial for any $a \in K$ has as its roots the elements in the orbit of $a$ under the action of $\text{Gal}(K/F)$.  That is, if $S = \{ \phi(a) \ | \ \phi \in \text{Gal}(K/F) \}$, then $\displaystyle \min_a(x) = \prod_{u_k \in S} (x-u_k)$.

*Proof*: This is a consequence of the fact that a polynomial is irreducible $\iff$ its Galois group acts [transitively](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitiveGroupAction.html) on its roots.  For a proof of this fact, see Theorem 2.9(b) [**here**](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisaspermgp.pdf).  Notice that $\displaystyle \min_a(x)$ will be an irreducible polynomial (by definition), and its Galois group will be a subgroup of $\text{Gal}(K/F)$.  This latter fact is because, if $L \subseteq K$ is the splitting field of $\displaystyle \min_a(x)$, every $F$-automorphism of $L$ [extends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_extension_theorem) to an $F$-automorphism of $K$. $\qquad \blacksquare$

---

For a candidate $\beta$ that we choose, we already have the inclusion $\mathbb{Q}(\beta) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.  Therefore, we just need to guarantee that $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ is a degree-$4$ extension of the rationals, or equivalently, that the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ is of degree $4$ -- this will imply that the two fields are equal.  To do this, first determine the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$.  Then, taking advantage of the above lemma, use some creativity to find an element that yields four distinct Galois conjugates when acted upon by this group.

Comment: Example : $\beta = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ works.