# Can $\sum_{n=2}^{k} \sqrt{n}$ be rational?

Tags: summation, irrational-numbers

It is easy to see that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ are irrational. So $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4}$ is irrational. But what about $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4} + \sqrt{5}$? I suspect that
$$\sum_{n=2}^{k} \sqrt{n}$$ is always irrational, is it true and is there a simple way to proof that?

Comment: @PeterForeman I don't disagree, but most likely the OP doesn't quite understand the terminology used in the question and answers there. They likely don't know what a $\mathbb Q$-vector space means, for example.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, as a sequence of roots of adjacent integers are added, not (typiccally) primes,.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442259/is-sqrt1-sqrt2-dots-sqrt-n-ever-an-integer) post which provides an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n}$ cannot be rational. Let $p$ be the greatest prime in $[2,n]$. By quadratic reciprocity and Dirichlet's theorem there is some huge prime $P\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ such that $p$ is a quadratic non-residue $\!\!\pmod{P}$, while the primes less than $p$ are quadratic residues $\!\!\pmod{P}$. It follows that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sqrt{n}$ does not belong to $\mathbb{F}_{P}$ but it belongs to a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{F}_P$. In particular it cannot be rational.

Comment: A delightful point of view!

Comment: I don't have the skills to understand the answer so I'm not sure that Exchange stack etiquette requires me to vote it. On the other hand, it seems a pity to me because there is a risk that good answers will go into oblivion.