# Show that $F\left(\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_k}\right) = F \left(\sqrt{d_1},...,\sqrt{d_k}\right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have some issues with this exercise. I have that F is a field and $d_1,...,d_k\in F\backslash\{0\}$

I have that $K:=F\left(\sqrt{d_1},...,\sqrt{d_k}\right)$

I have to show that $K=F\left(\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_k}\right)$. I have shown that $F\left(\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_k}\right) \subseteq F \left(\sqrt{d_1},...,\sqrt{d_k}\right)$ and now wants to show that $F\left(\sqrt{d_1},...,\sqrt{d_k}\right)\subseteq F\left(\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_k}\right)$. I am thinking of finding the conjugates of $\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_k}$ by finding the minimal polynomium in which $\sqrt {d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_k}$ is a root and then find the other roots of this minimal polynomium which will then be the conjugates. And then I am thinking of using these conjugates to say something about that $\sqrt{d_1},...,\sqrt{d_k} \in \left(\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_k}\right)$.

But I have problems finding the minimal polynomial in which $\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_k}$ is a root, so I am hoping that some of you can help me with that.

I have until now as well shown $[K:F]=2^k$. And I have shown that $K/F$ is Galois, and that for each $i=1,...,k$ $\sigma_i \in Gal(K/F)$ such that $\sigma_i\sqrt{d_j}=\sqrt{d_j}$ for $i\neq j$, but $\sigma_i \sqrt{d_i}=-\sqrt{d_i}$.

Comment: Have you tried induction on $k$?

Comment: Hi Gerry! Yes I have. For k=1 it is obvious because $F(\sqrt{d_1}) \subseteq F(\sqrt{d_1})$. Then I assume it holds for k i.e.$F(\sqrt{d_1},...,\sqrt{d_k}) \subseteq F(\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_k})$ and want to show that it holds for k+1 i.e. $F(\sqrt{d_1},...,\sqrt{d_{k+1}}) \subseteq F(\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_{k+1}})$ which gives me some problems.

Comment: You won't necessarily need to find the minimal polynomial of the sum of square roots. You can reuse the argument from [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442265/11619) if you also read the comments under it. But, it is not necessarily true that the degree of the extension is $2^k$, so you need to exercise a bit of care. For example, if $F=\Bbb{Q}$, $d_1=6$, $d_2=10$ and $d_3=15$ then ... See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619) for  more. Many good answers there.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have get a hint about considering the conjugates of $\sqrt{d_{1}}+...+\sqrt{d_{k}}$ and that's why I wanna find the conjugates, and that's what I am having a hard time doing

Comment: Ok. The details really depend on the eventual dependencies such as $\sqrt{6}\sqrt{10}\sqrt{15}=30$ among the different square roots.  The Galois theoretic idea is to show that the sum $S=\sqrt{d_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{d_n}$ satisfies $\sigma(S)\neq S$ for all the non-trivial elements $\sigma\in Gal(K/F)$. That is, after all, equivalent to $K=F(S)$. But there are a few pitfalls along the way. For example if $F$ has characteristic two, the extension is not Galois.

Comment: (cont'd)For a different kind of a problem: If $a_1+a_2+a_3=0$, then, by suitable choices of square roots, and $d_1=da_1^2, d_2=da_2^2, d_3=da_3^2$ we get $S=0$ even though $\sqrt{d}\in K\setminus F$. In other words, **the result may be false, if we are not given some extra information.**

Comment: The problems mentioned by @Jyrki are resolved by requiring that the radicals are multiplicatively independent over $F$, i..e. no product of distinct radicals lies in $F$, as in [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242), This generalizes to higher degree radicals - see the papers of Mordell and Siegel that I cite there. The algebraic essence of the matter is clarified when one studies Galois theory (of Kummer extensions).