# Prove $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}+...+\sqrt{p_{n}}$ is irrational, where $p_{n}$ is the nth prime.

Tags: irrational-numbers, rationality-testing, algebraic-numbers

My motivation is making general proof , instead of trying to prove special cases.

To which branch of mathematics does my question belong?

I am highly interested in irrational numbers.

Is it good idea , proving that the number in my question has algebraic degree higher than one(and why is degree greater than one implies number is irrational)?

I searched and I didn't find good references to my wondering.

Comment: This theme recurs. The argument from [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442265/11619) to a slightly different question works *as is* here as well. That method is arguably unnecessarily high-browed in that Galois theory is not strictly necessary. In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113689/11619) we still use field theory, and that may be necessary to settle questions like this (when the number of square roots grows, and purely arithmetical techniques become unwieldy).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen   Thanks

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30687/11619) is close to being an exact match. Check out the links in Qiaochu Yuan's answer. Olympiad style answers are promised. I haven't checked exactly what that means, but it usually implies that less advanced theory is required (but technical prowess goes up to compensate).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call $p_1:=2$, $p_2:=3$ and so on, $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number. Consider the set

$$E_n:=\{\varepsilon_1 \sqrt{p_1}+\ldots+\varepsilon_n \sqrt{p_n}:\ \varepsilon_i∈\{-1,1\}\}$$

so $E_n$ contains all $2^n$ possible combinations of sums and differences of the square roots $\sqrt2$, $\sqrt3$, $\ldots$, $\sqrt{p_n}$.

Now, consider the polynomial
$$p_n(x):=\prod_{\alpha\in E_n} (x-\alpha)$$

This is called the $n$th [Swinnerton-Dyer polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Swinnerton-DyerPolynomial.html), it is an irreducible polynomial with coefficient in $\mathbb Z$. So all its roots are irrational numbers with degree $2^n$

Comment: This is a fine method, of course (I upvoted). Proving that the polynomial is irreducible may not be too easy :-) I didn't know these were called Swinnerton-Dyer polynomials!

Comment: Thanks and I wanna ask you, how do we prove that coefficients are in $\mathbb{Z}$
And how to prove irreducibility?
I want you to guide me to good references.

Comment: Yeah, if I remember correctly there is a bit of Galois theory involved!