# Prove that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

I have proved in earlier exercises of this book that $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ are irrational. Then, the sum of two irrational numbers is an irrational number. Thus, $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is irrational. My first question is, is this reasoning correct?

Secondly, the book wants me to use the fact that if $n$ is an integer that is not a perfect square, then $\sqrt n$ is irrational. This means that $\sqrt 6$ is irrational. How are we to use this fact? Can we reason as follows:

$\sqrt 6$ is irrational

$\Rightarrow \sqrt{2 \cdot 3}$ is irrational.

$\Rightarrow \sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 3$ is irrational

$\Rightarrow \sqrt 2$ or $\sqrt 3$ or both are irrational.

$\Rightarrow \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is irrational.

Is this way of reasoning correct?

Comment: The sum of two irrational numbers need not be irrational. $\sqrt{2} + (-\sqrt{2}) = 0$, for example.

Comment: your first reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: Very nice! Now what about the second part?

Comment: The third step in the second problem is not right. $2\sqrt{2}$ is irrational does not imply both $2$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are irrational.

Comment: Still incorrect, @dotslash : product of irrationals isn't necessarily irrational.

Comment: @DonAntonio In that case, if I remove the "both" clause, the proof works?

Comment: I can't see how, @dotslash ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean, if the product of two numbers is irrational, doesn't it follow that at least one of them has to be irrational? And if so, their sum will also be irrational.

Comment: Ok @dotslash, so you mean that $\;ab\notin\Bbb Q\implies a+b\notin \Bbb Q\,$ ? But I'm not sure whether this is true and anyway I think it deserves proof.

Comment: Hmmm, I see the point. Thanks for your helpful comments!

Comment: If $a=2^{1/4}$ and $b=-2^{1/4}$, then $ab\not\in \mathbb Q$ but $a+b\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Etienne Excellent counter-example! Many thanks for your contribution.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278935/can-a-finite-sum-of-square-roots-be-an-integer/278945

Comment: what book are you talking about?

Comment: Does it matter? Especially now? :)

Comment: What book did you get this question from out of interest ?

Comment: I guess it was Discrete Mathematics by Susanna Epp

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ is rational, then so is $(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})^2 = 5 + 2 \sqrt{6}$. But this is absurd since $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational.

Comment: Love the usage of the word absurd!

Comment: May be a proof by contradiction...

Answer (score 63):

If $\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 2$ is rational/irrational, then so is $\sqrt 3 -\sqrt 2$ because $\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 2=\large \frac {1}{\sqrt 3- \sqrt 2}$ . Now assume $\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 2$ is rational. If we add $(\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 2)+(\sqrt 3 -\sqrt 2)$ we get $2\sqrt 3$ which is irrational. But the sum of two rationals can never be irrational, because for integers $a, b, c, d$ $\large \frac ab+\frac cd=\frac {ad+bc}{bd}$ which is rational. Therefore, our assumption that $\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 2$ is rational is incorrect, so $\sqrt 3 +\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Answer (score 30):

Hints:

Suppose there exist coprime $\,a,b\in\Bbb Z\,$ s.t.

$$\sqrt2+\sqrt3=\frac ab\implies \sqrt6=\frac{a^2}{2b^2}-\frac52=\frac{a^2-5b^2}{2b^2}$$

If you already know $\,\sqrt6\,$ is irrational then you're already done, otherwise prove it as with $\,\sqrt2\,$ , say:

$$\sqrt6=\frac pq\;,\;\;(p,q)=1\implies 6q^2=p^2\implies 2\mid p$$

and thus we can write

$$\sqrt6=\frac{2p'}q\implies 2\mid q\;\;\;\;\text{also , and this is a contradiction}$$

Comment: The accepted answer gives the OP a fish. Your answer teach him to fish.

Comment: one small nit detail - we need to say p,q are co prime as well [i.e. p/q is in simplest form].

Comment: I don't understand, should it not be $2\sqrt6$ instead of just $\sqrt6$? I am referring to when you squared both sides of $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3 = \frac{a}{b}$

Comment: @ashimashi I most second this stance. This answer seems to involve incorrect arithmetic!

Comment: @ashimashi Yes, it seems to be lacking a **rational** factor of two there, but (1) it doesn't affect the outcome, and (2) this was so much time ago...I shall edit it, however. THanks

Answer (score 14):

If $\sqrt2+\sqrt3 =r \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\frac{r^2-5}{2}=\sqrt6 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Contradiction! This could be a way of your proof.

Answer (score 13):

Note that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is a solution to the equation: $$x^4-10x^2+1=0$$Does this polynomial have any rational roots?

Edit: To find this polynomial, note that if $x=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, then: $$x^2=5+2\sqrt{6}$$and: $$x^4=49+20\sqrt{6}.$$You need $-10x^2$'s to get rid of the $20\sqrt{6}$ in $x^4$, and $x^4-10x^2=-1$, so you get: $$x^4-10x^2+1=0.$$

Comment: Or use $(x^2-5)^2=24$

Answer (score 10):

Your reasoning is not correct when you go from $\sqrt 2 $ or $ \sqrt 3$ or both are irrational to $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is irrational.

I would say:  assume $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is rational.  Then its square is rational, because multiplying rationals gives a rational.  But $(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)^2=2+2\sqrt 6 +3$ is irrational because the sum of an irrational and a rational ($5$) is irrational, so we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 8):

If you know anything about Galois theory, here is a very roundabout way of proving this (in other words, the other answers are better ways to think about this problem):

$\alpha=\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3$ is a primitive element of the Galois extension 
$[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]$, with minimal poylnomial
$(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$, which has degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  It follows that $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3\notin\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I am not sure how this will help the OP.

Comment: Well @LordSoth, **if** the OP knows Galois Theory then the above answers his question...of course, if he knows Galois theory then asking this question is completely anachronical (mathematicalwise)

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, that was my point.

Comment: For the record, I don't know Galois Theory. :)

Comment: It seems to me that this answer just asserts without proof a stronger statement than what the OP asked, namely that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $4$ (the OP asked for a proof that it does not have degree $1$).  In order for this to be a reasonable answer, shouldn't you say *something* about how to prove this stronger statement?

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to prove that the sum of two irrational numbers yields an irrational number first. Note that its not true though. So to your first question, your reasoning is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out, the sum of
two irrational numbers can be rational,
so your proof is invalid.

This is even true if both numbers
are positive, as the following shows:

> Let $a = 0.12112111211112...$
>   and form $b$ by changing every $1$ in $a$
>   to a $2$ and every $2$ to $1$.
>
> So $b = 0.21221222122221...$

Clearly $a$ and $b$ are irrational,
but $a+b = 0.33333... = \frac 13$,
which is a rational number.

Comment: $\sqrt{2},\,1-\sqrt{2}$ work too. I didn't downvote though.

Comment: @user26486 $1-\sqrt{2}$ is not positive, but I get your point