# Prove $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}$ is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers, radicals

How do you prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}$ is irrational?

I tried to prove it by contradiction and got this equation:  $a^2/b^2 = \sqrt{40}$.

Comment: See here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496037/prove-that-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-is-irrational/496102#496102

Comment: I have posted answer for this two times in this forum... please try checking with some key words...

Comment: Square the number: if it's rational, then also $\sqrt{10}$ is. Is it?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik *Which* key words? $\sqrt{2}$ isn't exactly eacy to search for...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use proof by contradiction. Assume that the sum is rationial, that is $$\sqrt2 +\sqrt5 = {a\over b}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers with $b\neq0$. Now rewrite this as $$\sqrt5={a\over b}-\sqrt2.$$ Squaring both sides of this equation we obtain $$5={a^2\over b^2}-2\sqrt2{a\over b}+2.$$ Now, carefully solve for $\sqrt2$ and obtain $$\sqrt2={-3b\over 2a}+{a\over 2b.}$$ This implies that $\sqrt2$ is a rational number which is a contradiction. Thus $$\sqrt2+\sqrt5$$ is an irrational number.

Answer (score 24):

$\sqrt 2=\dfrac 12\left(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5-\dfrac 3{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5}\right)\notin\mathbb Q$, hence $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 5\notin \mathbb Q$

Answer (score 12):

You have $$(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5})^2 = 7 + 2\sqrt{10}.$$
The square of a  rational number is rational.  This number,
$7 + 2\sqrt{10}$,  is rational iff $\sqrt{10}$ is rational. The standard argument shows that $\sqrt{10}$ is not rational.  So we are done here.

Comment: You're almost correct. Square of a rational number is rational, but the square of an irrational number can be rational. So the "iff" is wrong in this context, but one implication, which is the one we use, is in fact true.

Comment: I am saying $9 + 2\sqrt{10}$ is rational iff $\sqrt{10}$ is ratioinal.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Thomas

Comment: Ah, that's better.

Answer (score 9):

Let  $\sqrt2+\sqrt5=a$ where $a$ is rational

$\implies\sqrt2=a-\sqrt5$

Squaring we get, $$2=a^2+5-2a\sqrt5\iff\sqrt5=\frac{a^2+3}{2a}$$ which is rational unlike $\sqrt5$

Comment: can you explain how you went from the squaring to this result 2=a2+5−2a5–√5

Comment: @AviPars, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction#Irrationality_of_the_square_root_of_2

Answer (score 7):

If your arrival at the equation $a^2/b^2=\sqrt{40}$ was correct, you’re done, because the equation $a^4=40b^4$ for integers $a$ and $b$ is a contradiction to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, which says that the expression of an integer as product of primes can be done in only one way. But your suspect fourth-degree equation has a number of $5$’s on the left that is divisible by $4$, but not so on the right.

Answer (score 4):

If $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$, i.e., $ \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}=\frac{b}{a}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \mbox{ and } a\neq 0$ then $ 2-5=\frac{b}{a}(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{5})$ and
$$
\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{5} =\frac{-3\cdot a}{b}
$$
Here $b$ is necessarily greater than zero by cause $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5}>0$.Finally we get,
$$
\sqrt{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left( (\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5})+(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{5}) \right)= \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{b}{a}+\frac{-3\cdot a}{b} \right)\in\mathbb{Q}.
$$
But this is a contradiction since $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.