# Prove the next numbers are irrational

Tags: calculus

I need to prove the next numbers are irrational:

$$ \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{5} $$
$$\sqrt{3}$$
$$ \log_{2}3  $$

Of course, I tried to prove it with negative evidence...

Comment: Show  us the efforts you have made so far.

Answer (score 1):

For first two, look at the links below (in comments). I am writing a short proof for the third.

Assume on the contrary it is rational, that is $$ \log_{2}3 =p/q $$ where $p$ and $q$ are integers and $q\neq 0$.

Now, multiplying $q$ on both sides, we get $$q \log_{2}3  =p$$

It implies, $2^{p}=3^{q}$.

We arrive at the contradiction as left hand side is even but right hand side is odd.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930486/prove-that-the-square-root-of-3-is-irrational

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539266/prove-sqrt2-sqrt5-is-irrational