# Proving that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational

Tags: radicals, rationality-testing

This is from Spivak.

Prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

So far, I have this:

If $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is rational, then it can be written as $\frac{p}{q}$ with integral $p, q$ and in lowest terms.

$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=\frac{p}{q}$$
$$2\sqrt{6}+5 =\frac{p^2}{q^2}$$
$$(2\sqrt{6}+5)q^2=p^2$$

And that's about where I get stuck. In a similar question (prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}$ is irrational,) I was able to show that both $p,q$ had to be even which is impossible. I obviously can't apply this trick here. Any hints?

Comment: Try squaring again after moving around some terms.

Comment: See the following [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457382/can-sqrtn-sqrtm-be-rational-if-neither-n-m-are-perfect-squares).

Comment: If you see on the right side of the screen, under "Related", your question appears twice ...

Comment: There are still twice as many who've answered than who've up-voted the question.

Comment: Good catch, @MauroALLEGRANZA . +1

Comment: Oddly, those didn't come up when I searched. I saw those after posting and was going to close, but then people started answering. Still, it's been helpful.

Comment: Also duplicates: [Prove that $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ is irrational](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496037/prove-that-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-is-irrational) and [Can $\sqrt n+\sqrt m$ be rational if neither $n,m$ are perfect squares?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457382/can-sqrtn-sqrtm-be-rational-if-neither-n-m-are-perfect-squares)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)(\sqrt3-\sqrt2)=3-2=1$ is rational, so if the first factor were rational, so would be the second, and their difference $2\sqrt2$. But surely you know that the latter isn't rational.

Comment: A very clever answer

Comment: This is clever and very simple. I barely missed this idea. I was trying to do stuff with conjugates, but didn't quite connect the dots.

Comment: @Josh See my [answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/674038/242) for a much more general application of this idea. I didn't mention it in my answer since I thought you were interested only in completing your approach. Genrally there are *many* ways to do such irrationality proofs.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\ \sqrt2 +\sqrt3 = r\in\Bbb Q\,\overset{\large\rm square}\Rightarrow\ 5+2\sqrt 6 = r^2 \,\Rightarrow\ \sqrt 6 = (r^2-5)/2 \in \Bbb Q,\,$ contradiction,

since $\,\sqrt{6} = a/b\,\Rightarrow\, 6b^2 = a^2\,$ has an odd number of $2$'s on the LHS, but an even number on RHS (by *uniqueness* of prime factorizations).

There are also many other ways, e.g. using the Rational Root Test on its minimal polynomial, or using Bezout, etc see prior posts here.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$. Then this is a solution to the equation $0=x^4-10x^2+1$. By rational root theorem, this equation has no rational solution. Therefore, $x$ must be irrational.

Comment: Could you please share how you came up with that equation?

Comment: @vonbrand He brought the radical 2 to the left, then squared both sides. Then he isolated the radical 2 term and squared both sides again...

Comment: @vonbrand [There are several answer to that question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/359054/25554).

Answer (score 2):

Ideas:

$$\sqrt2+\sqrt3=\frac pq\implies 3=\frac{p^2}{q^2}-2\frac pq\sqrt2+2\implies$$

$$\sqrt2=\left(\frac{p^2}{q^2}-1\right)\frac q{2p}\in\Bbb Q\;\ldots$$

Comment: Three answer so far, but I'm the only one who's up-voted the question.

Comment: That's because you are sooooo nice, @MichaelHardy...:) Here, I'm upvoting it, too.

Comment: Oh: I intended this comment to be under the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

If $2\sqrt{6} + 5 = p^2/q^2$, then $\displaystyle \sqrt{6} = \frac 1 2 \left(\frac{p^2}{q^2} - 5\right)$, so $\sqrt{6}$ is rational.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem by contradiction. Suppose that it is rational, so it is a non-zero rational number such as $\frac{a}{b}$.

$(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})=1\rightarrow \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{b}{a}$

So we conclude that $\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number as well.

$\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}=\frac{b}{a}\rightarrow 5-2\sqrt{6}=(\frac{b}{a})^2$

$\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}\rightarrow 5+2\sqrt{6}=(\frac{a}{b})^2$

Subtract the former equation from the latter one, we conclude $4\sqrt{6}=(\frac{a}{b})^2-(\frac{b}{a})^2$

From above equation we conclude $\sqrt{6}$ is rational, but we can prove the irrationality of $\sqrt{6}$ quite simple(It has been brought in following) which shows contradiction and hence $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

**proof for irrationality of $\sqrt{6}$**

If it is rational then it is equal to $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime natural numbers. then $p^2=6q^2\rightarrow q^2|p^2\rightarrow$ $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime if and only if $q=1$ which implies 6 is a square integer which is a contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

From your very last step:
 $$\sqrt{6} = \frac{p^2 - 5q^2}{2q^2}$$ This a rational number- a contradiction, hence the answer.

Comment: You were mentioned in this meta thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/what-do-you-do-with-a-user-that-does-not-want-to-learn-latex . It does seem strange that answers such as this are not formatted using MathJax.