# Is $\sqrt{4+\pi} + \sqrt{4-\pi} \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

Prove or disprove that $\sqrt{4+\pi} + \sqrt{4-\pi} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What have you tried? What tools and facts do you have at your disposal? Are you, for instance, allowed to use the fact that $\pi$ is trancendental?

Comment: Try using a similar approach to [proving that $\sqrt2$ is irrational](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Proof_by_contradiction)?

Comment: Also see this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726421/proving-that-sqrt2-sqrt3-is-irrational?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If $\sqrt{4+\pi}+\sqrt{4-\pi}\in\mathbb{Q}$, $\pi$ would be algebraic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that:

$$\sqrt{4 + \pi} + \sqrt{4 - \pi} = r \in \mathbb{Q}$$

If you square that expression, you get:

$$4 + \pi + 2 \sqrt{16 - \pi^2} + 4 - \pi = r^2$$

If you simplify this a little bit you get:

$$2 \sqrt{16 - \pi^2} = r^2 - 8$$

or:

$${\pi^2} = 16-{({{r^2-8}\over {2}})^2} \in\mathbb{Q} $$

...which is not true because $\pi^2$ is not a rational number. Therefore, your expression is not a rational number.

EDIT: If you have to prove that $\pi^2$ is irrational, try the opposite. Say that:

$$\pi^2={p\over q}$$

where $p,q$ are whole numbers. You get the following equation:

$$q \pi^2 - p = 0$$

But $\pi$ is a transcendent number and cannot appear as a solution of any equation of the form:

$$q x^2 - p = 0 $$

with $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$. So our initial assumption that $\pi^2$ is a rational number is definitely false.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Let $q=\sqrt{4+\pi} + \sqrt{4-\pi}\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then
$$q^2=4+\pi+4-\pi+2\sqrt{4+\pi}\cdot\sqrt{4-\pi}=16+2\sqrt{16-\pi^2},$$
which implies that $\pi^2=?$. Finally recall that [$\pi^2$ is irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Hermite.27s_proof).

Comment: Just to be clear, the irrationality of $\pi$ does not imply the irrationality of $\pi^2$. You need the fact of the transcendence of $\pi$ for that inference.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks. I forgot the square.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that $\sqrt{4 + \pi}+\sqrt{4 -\pi} = q \in \mathbb{Q}$

Square and rearrange to get: $2\sqrt{16 - \pi^2} = q^2 - 4$ [equation 1]

If you're allowed to assume that $\pi$ is transcendental, then square equation 1 again to get:

$4(16 - \pi^2) = (q^2 - 4)^2$, which can be rearranged to give a polynomial with integral coefficients satisfied by $\pi$, hence leading to a contradiction.

If you can't assume the transcendence of $\pi$, then you have to prove $\pi^2$ is irrational, which can be done using the (not exactly elementary) technique here: http://planetmath.org/piandpi2areirrational