# Prove irrationality of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ and $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals, rationality-testing

I am trying to prove the irrationality of the above two numbers, but I don't know how. What would be a general strategy for problems like these?

My current strategy is trying to reach a contradiction by starting with $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{a}{b}$ with integers $a$ and $b$ and somehow reaching that $a$ needs to be both even and odd for example. But I keep getting stuck.

Comment: If a number is rational, so is its square. And I think you know that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Comment: Consider asking two separate questions (or just remove the $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ part because that has already been answered here).

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. Then

$$(x-\sqrt{2})^2=3=x^2-2\sqrt{2}x+2$$

$$\sqrt{2}=\frac{x^2-1}{2x}$$

Then if $x$ is rational, so is $\sqrt{2}$, contradiction.

If $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$, then $x^2-2=\sqrt{2}$, same idea then.

Comment: There are nine answers already [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452078/prove-that-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-is-irrational).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know. There are dozens of questions of this kind on MSE.

Comment: You are right, and sometimes one can answer it again, but here we could just copy and paste - this cannot be the idea of MSE. Why not mark it as a duplicate instead of repeating an answer ?

Answer (score 2):

No proof by contradiction is required: the minimal polynomials of $x$ are, respectively: $x^4-10x^2+1\,$  and $\,x^4-4x^2+2$.

By the Rational Root theorem, if $x$ were rational, it would be an integer that is a divisor of the constant term. Test the possibilities, and check none is a root.

Comment: Because I didn't know there was already a similar answer. Having checked, I give some  more details (and also some less). Do you think I should withdraw my answer?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: I don't agree; it's only examining all possible cases.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. I know some would say so, however (see Dietrich' comment above). And some would even downvote (I was downvoted a couple of hours ago, on a correct answer). I don't like that kind of behaviour, even if I don't like either when students ask questions here without any work, and without even looking if the question was asked before.

Comment: Btw, I was also downvoted here. How fun.

Answer (score 1):

To use the even/odd idea, note that $$2b^2+b^2\sqrt 2=a^2$$

Now $$(a^2-2b^2)^2=2b^4=a^4-4a^2b^2+4b^4$$ whence $$a^4-4a^2b^2+2b^2=0$$ so that $$a^4=4a^2b^2-2b^4$$From this $a$ must be even ($2c$, say) $$16c^4=16c^2b^2-2b^4$$ or $$8c^4=8c^2b^2-b^4$$ and $b$ must also be even.

The rational root theorem amounts to a systematic generalisation of this idea.