# An elementary way to prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

An elementary way to prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational?

- Disclaimer: I know about the rational root theorem. I am trying to answer it without using it.

I did the following:

$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}=\frac{a}{b}$$

$$5+2\sqrt{6}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$

$$24=\frac{a^4}{b^4}-10\frac{a^2}{b^2} + 25$$

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}\left(10-\frac{a^2}{b^2} \right)= 1$$

At this point, I am a bit confused. I thought about this: If $A=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ then $A^{-1}=\left(10-\frac{a^2}{b^2} \right)$ and then:

$$AA^{-1}=A\left(10-A \right)=10A-A^2=1\tag{$\star$}$$

This is a polynomial with roots: $A=5\pm 2\sqrt{6}$ which means that:

$$\frac{a^2}{b^2}=5\pm 2\sqrt{6}$$

$$\frac{a^2}{2b^2}-\frac{5}{2}=\pm \sqrt{6}$$

As $\frac{a^2}{2b^2}-\frac{5}{2}$ is rational and $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational, then we obtain a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: Hint: by your 2nd equation it suffices to show $\sqrt 6\not\in \Bbb Q$ (which can be done the same way as $\sqrt 2,$ for which there are *hundreds* of prior answers here).

Comment: Duplicate of [Prove that $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452078/prove-that-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-is-irrational) and likely *hundreds* more.

Answer (score 1):

From your second line of working you should get that
$$5+2\sqrt{6}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\implies\sqrt{6}=\frac{a^2-5b^2}{2b^2}\in\mathbb{Q}$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Damn. I ended up saying a lot of stuff to just say what I was already saying! *facepalm*.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is corect but you could have stopped on the second line and get the same result.

You have $$ 5+2\sqrt{6}=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$ which  implies that $\sqrt 6$ is rational and that is a contradiction that you are looking for.

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Trusted users should A) search first when a question smells like a duplicate, and B) IMHO also steer clear from stunning displays of banalities. Not saying that it is always easy to resist the temptation to answer every trivial thing, but...

Answer (score 1):

It may be addressed in *vast* generality, to wit:

Let

$r, s \in \Bbb N, \tag 1$

neither of which is a perfect square; if

$\sqrt r + \sqrt s = q \in \Bbb Q, \tag 2$

then

$\sqrt r = q - \sqrt s, \tag 3$

which upon squaring leads to

$r = q^2 - 2q\sqrt s + s = (q^2 + s) - 2q\sqrt s, \tag 4$

$2q\sqrt s = (q^2 + s) - r, \tag 5$

and thus

$\sqrt s = \dfrac{(q^2 + s) - r}{2q} \in \Bbb Q, \tag 6$

valid since $q \ne 0$ from (2); but this contradicts the well-known fact that an integer which is not a perfect square cannot have a rational square root, proved, for example, in [the answers to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329462/is-my-proof-that-the-square-root-of-all-imperfect-squares-are-irrational-correct).

Now we simply set

$r = 2, \; s = 3, \tag 7$

to obtain the specific result requested in the question title.

And so we are done.