# $\sqrt 1+\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3 +\cdots +\sqrt {2009}$ change a sign to be rational

Tags: number-theory, summation, radicals, rationality-testing

I have this problem:

$$\sqrt 1+\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 3 +\cdots +\sqrt {2009}$$

Prove that you need to change ONLY a sign (to convert a $+$ to $-$) of a single square root, for the sum to be rational.

EDIT: My math book was wrong. This exercise is not correct.

Can you help me please? I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: That doesn't sound very likely, are you sure?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I am sure.

Comment: I, too, would like to call shenanigans.  How are you sure?

Comment: @tilper It is an exercise in my math book.

Comment: Interesting.  When I get home later today I can play around with this on Maple.

Comment: The sum contains a term of $\sqrt{2003}$.   But $2003$ is prime, so none of the other terms in the sum add up to $\sqrt{2003}$ or to any multiple of it.  There is no way to make the sum rational while that $\sqrt{2003}$ is in there.

Comment: This math book wouldn't happen to be called "the mathematics of the Simpsons" would it?

Comment: Ok. I asked my math teacher by phone and she said the exercise is wrong and to change them to another but based on the same. I am editing the question. Or shoud I post a new question? Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Can a finite sum of square roots be an integer?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278935)

Comment: Sorry because my math book was wrong!! Sorry!!!!!

Comment: @MMPP I would ask a new question since there is already a good answer to the currently posed question.

Comment: My answer to your previous question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867912/for-pm-sqrt-1-pm-sqrt-2-pm-sqrt-3-pm-cdots-pm-sqrt-2009-show-there-is-a) proves that, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Impossible!  Let $K$ be the field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\sqrt{k}$, for $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,2009\}\setminus\{2003\}$.  Then, $\sqrt{2003}$ is not contained in $K$ due to [a result](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.630.1024&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by I. Boreico.  Hence, $\sqrt{2003}$ can not be a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of $\sqrt{k}$ for $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,2009\}\setminus\{2003\}$.  In fact, no matter how many signs you flip, it is never possible to make the sum a rational number.

Comment: The result you refer to is much older than that - sometimes credited to Besicovitch. You can find a proof in my [answer here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30707/242)