# Prove that $\sqrt{a_1}\pm \sqrt{a_2}\pm\ldots\pm \sqrt{a_n}$ is irrational for $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_i\neq m^2$

Tags: summation, radicals, irrational-numbers

Consider a sequence $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ such that $a_1,a_2,\ldots a_n\in\mathbb{N_{\ge 1}}$, $a_1\neq a_2\neq \ldots\neq a_n$ and for every $1\le i\le n$, $a_i$ is square-free.

$$ \sqrt{a_1}\pm \sqrt{a_2}\pm\ldots\pm \sqrt{a_n}$$

is an irrational number.

This question originates from solving a AoPS Olympiad problem (prove that $\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational) - I was wondering if this could be generalized to sequences of arbitraly length.

Comment: Are $a_i$ all pairwise distinct?

Comment: Yes, I'll modify the question.

Comment: This is false as stated, consider $\sqrt{18}-\sqrt{8}-\sqrt{2}$. It is true once you assume $a_i$ are squarefree, however.

Comment: Modified the question appropriately.

Comment: (you still have to assume $a_i\neq 1$; earlier it was contained in the assumption that they aren't squares)

Comment: Modified again, thanks for helpful comments!

Comment: $a_1\neq a_2\neq \ldots\neq a_n$, I don't think it means what you want. You should write $i \neq j \Rightarrow a_i \neq a_j$.

Comment: Well, $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = q \implies \sqrt{xy} = (q-x-y)/2$ is rational.  but x and y being squarefree and inequal makes this impossible.  Can probably generalize for induction.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278935/can-a-finite-sum-of-square-roots-be-an-integer) and [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/437374).