# Is there a natural number satisfying the given condition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, integers, natural-numbers

Is there a positive integer $n$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sqrt{n+k}$ is also an integer?

Comment: No, there is no such $n$. The proof is similar to [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442259/is-sqrt1-sqrt2-dots-sqrt-n-ever-an-integer).

Comment: @DietrichBurde However, my problem is different from that. That starts with $\sqrt_{1}+\dots$, but my problem may start with any positive integer $n$ (i.e. $\sqrt_{n}+\sqrt_{n+1}+\dots+\sqrt_{2n}$

Comment: No, the above [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278935/can-a-finite-sum-of-square-roots-be-an-integer) is for an **arbitrary** sum of square roots of non-negative integers. And since for $a\ge 1$ being a perfect square, $a+1$ is not a perfect square, we are done.