# Usage of commas in sets as "such that"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I can't find this anywhere, but a particular lecturer that I have seems to be using commas to mean "such that" in sets. I'm seeking clarification on whether this really is the case or if I'm just misinterpreting.
Example:
$$\{U_1 \times U_2, U_1 \textit{open in }X_1, U_2 \textit{open in }X_2\}.$$
Is this the same as
$$\{U_1 \times U_2| U_1 \textit{open in }X_1, U_2 \textit{open in }X_2\}?$$

Comment: That's probably what they mean. It's unfortunate about the first comma, though if the second is meant to be interpreted as a logical "and", that's not so bad.

Comment: The thing is, it's not a one time thing, The lecturer has been doing this over the whole course, switching between using $,$ $|$ and $:$ so I wanted to know if using $,$ is actually "correct".

Comment: The usage is not uncommon, in both mathematical English and ordinary English. For example, one can write $\Pr(A,B \mid C$ to mean the probability of $A$ **and** $B$, given $C$.

Comment: @André Nicolas Just to clear that up, I don't mean the usage of $,$ to mean "and", but to mean "such that".

Comment: If the lecturer is speaking as he says this, and explains what he means, good... But when it is written, not so good.

Comment: This usage is not the most common, but it doesn't seem wrong, either. It's similar in meaning to the first comma in "Let $a_i = i^2, i = 1,\dots, n$" or "the numbers $i^2, i = 1, \dots, n$." If you're allowed to write things like $\{U_1 \times U_2\}$, then there's no clear reason a comma like that one shouldn't be allowed inside the braces without a $\mid$.

Comment: It should be noted that the meaning of $\mid$ in a notation like $\{x^2 \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is fundamentally different from what it means in one like $\{x \mid  x^2 + 5 = 9 \}$. The first is short for $\{y \mid \exists x \in \mathbb{R} \, y = x^2\}$. I wouldn't be surprised if some people objected to using $\mid$ in cases like the first, and might prefer to use some other symbol to distinguish the two concepts. Your example with $\{ U_1 \times U_2 \}$ is an example of the first kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not wrong to use "$,$" for "such that" in this context (however, it is not usual). In fact, from the logical point of view, we can use any symbol to denote anything (after all, [truth is invariant under changes of notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1093725/70305)). The point is: the notation's meaning have to be at least (i) clear for the reader and (ii) unambiguous.

In the first set in your post, the symbol "$,$" has two different meanings (as explained in the @par 's comment). So, I'd say that the comma's use is being inappropriate. But, of course, for the experienced reader this use will not cause problems.

> By relieving the brain of all unnecessary work, a good notation sets it free to concentrate on more advanced problems, and, in effect, increases the mental power of the race. (Alfred North Whitehead) - From [Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/use-good-notation/).

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct. The usual (and better) notation is $$\{U_1 \times U_2:\, U_1 \text{ open in }X_1 \text{ and } U_2 \text{ open in }X_2\}.$$

Comment: Rather than knowing if my interpretation is correct, I'm interested in knowing if the lecturer is correct in using such notation.

Comment: @IrregularUser: In short, no. But there is an element of opinion regarding notation. What one person regards as accurate, another will consider cumbersome and time-consuming, like "Come on; you know what I mean. Don't be pedantic."

Answer (score 1):

No one can say that it's wrong to use a comma like that since we might just not have seen the convention your teacher is using, but I've never seen a convention where you can use a comma like that. Either "$:$" or "$|$" would be fine in place of the comma.